# How to apply reciprocity theorem to h parameters?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I know the result is h12 = -h21, but it's strange since h12 = V1/V2 and h21 = I2/I1.

Reciprocity theorem says that ratio of excitation to result must remain same if they are interchanged, how do you arrive at that result from the statement?

Comment: What is the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reciprocity theorem says that ratio of excitation to result must remain same if they are interchanged

No, the reciprocity theorem does not say that. That is just the *definition* of reciprocity (actually, not well stated). The reciprocity theorem states, instead, that a certain specific class of networks, that of networks composed of resistors, inductors, capacitors, and transformers, *is* reciprocal.

First, let me start with a better definition of reciprocal network [1]:

> A reciprocal network is one in which, for any pair of excitation and response points, here labeled 1 and 2, \$I_1 = I_2\$ if \$V_1 = V_2\$.

Notice that when you set a current excitation you should look at the voltage response and viceversa.

Consider now the hybrid representation of a two-port network,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} V_1 \\ I_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} h_{11} & h_{12} \\ h_{21} & h_{22} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} I_1 \\ V_2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Set, e.g, a current excitation at port 1, \$I_1 = I\$, and look at the *open circuit* voltage response at port 2, that is, find \$V_2\$ when \$I_1 = I\$ and \$I_2 = 0\$. Plugging these conditions into the matrix equation above, yields

$$ \begin{pmatrix} V_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} h_{11} & h_{12} \\ h_{21} & h_{22} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} I \\ V_2 \end{pmatrix},$$

from which we obtain

$$V_2 = -\frac{h_{21}}{h_{22}}I.$$

Now exchange the position of the excitation and the response: set \$I_2 = I\$, \$I_1 = 0\$ and find \$V_1\$. From

$$ \begin{pmatrix} V_1 \\ I \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} h_{11} & h_{12} \\ h_{21} & h_{22} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ V_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

we get

$$V_1 = \frac{h_{12}}{h_{22}}I.$$

The reciprocity condition requires the two responses to be equal, \$V_1 = V_2\$, that is,

$$\frac{h_{12}}{h_{22}}I = -\frac{h_{21}}{h_{22}}I$$

from which \$h_{12} = -h_{21}\$.

[1] N. Balabanian, T. A. Bickart, *Electrical network theory*, John Wiley & Sons, Inc., 1969.